# Conda: failed to install package from local tar.bz2 file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I build my own conda package, and generated my pack.tar.bz2 file. I was trying to install this package on another machine from the pack.tar.bz2 file.

I ran `conda install path-to-pack.tar.bz2`

I got below exception:

```
`$ C:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py install ./bin/pack.tar.bz2`

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 479, in con
da_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 145, in _main

        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 80, i
n execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 209, in in
stall
        explicit(args.packages, prefix, verbose=not context.quiet)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\misc.py", line 175, in explicit
        index.update(get_index(**index_args))
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\api.py", line 24, in get_index
        index = fetch_index(channel_urls, use_cache=use_cache, unknown=unknown)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 295, in fetch_in
dex
        for url in urls]
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 75, in func
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 117, in fetch_re
podata
        timeout=(6.1, 60))
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 501, in ge
t
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in re
quest
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 641, in se
nd
        r.content
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 781, in cont
ent
        self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b
ytes()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 714, in gene
rate
        chunk = self.raw.read(chunk_size)
    AttributeError: 'exceptions.WindowsError' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Please let me know what can be a fix.

Comment: I keep having this issue, and would love to know how to fix it